# Service Policy CISCO 7606 not work

Tags: cisco, qos

I have bandwidth control in cisco 7606 but the same is not limiting my clients. I checked the settings and did not identify an error. This box is 1 replacement for 1 old 7606 model. Is it necessary to enable the "qos" in some way for the bandwidth to work?
Here is an example:

"policy-map CUST-1G-Egress
 class class-default
   police rate 1000000000
      conform-action transmit
      exceed-action drop "

NOTE: mls qos is enabled.

Comment: Please, never use an image of text in your question. You should simply copy and paste the text into your post, and use the Preformatted-text feature (`{}`). Please edit the question to include the full (sanitized;  obfuscate any public addresses and passwords) configuration.

Comment: Either I'm limited on my mobile and cannot see the entire question, or you did not show how and where this this policy-map is attached to a (sub)interface, service instance or SVI. Can you please add this information?

Comment: He didn't say "REMOVE the picture"; he said *replace* it with the text it contains. (for the exact reason you just created: we're now missing information because the picture isn't available.)